# Save recyclerview items in Firebase recycle Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebaseRecyclerAdapter constantly reading a JSON file in the database and displaying the data everytime the app is opened, is there a way to save the items that were already displayed so only the ones that are updated or missing are downloaded?

The structure of the JSON:

```
  "Category" : {
    "01" : {
      "desc" : "test",
      "image" : "imageUrl",
      "title" : "Test",
      "urlNoticia" : "url2"
    },
     "02" : {
          "desc" : "test2",
          "image" : "imgUrl2",
          "title" : "Tes2t",
          "urlNoticia" : "url2"
        }
```

My holder:

```
public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imagePost;
    public TextView titlePost;
    public TextView descPost;


    public MenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imagePost = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        titlePost = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        descPost = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);

    }      
}
```

My adapter:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(noticasOpciones) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MenuViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Category model) {
        holder.titlePost.setText(model.getTitle());
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(model.getImage())
                .into(holder.imagePost);

        holder.descPost.setText(model.getDesc());
        final Category clickItem = model;

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //Open a new fragment

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

        return new MenuViewHolder(view);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [enable disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence), the Firebase client will persist the data it receives to disk. When you later (e.g. after a restart) listen for the same data, the client will initially load the data from disk and then update it from the server. This typically uses less bandwidth than if you simply reload all data.

Comment: But if I want to add a new item in the database that does not allow me to modify the JSON file, or Im doing something wrong?